# Intel array notation vector operations

Tags: c, intel, cilk-plus

Intel documentation doesn't clarify if one does e.g. multiplication and addition of arrays:

```
c[:] = c[:] + a[:]*b[:]
```

will it do the following:

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++) tmp[i] = a[i]*b[i];
for(i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = c[i] + tmp[i];
```

OR

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = c[i] + a[i]*b[i];
```

For large arrays there is a significant performance difference. As far as I know when such vector operations are done using STL vectors, the former one is done.

Thank you in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array notation in icc 12.1 generated the temporary, since that is what Fortran does and it seemed safer.  Then we discovered that the temporaries, as the question notes, can have a big performance impact.  So array notation was revised in icc 13.0 (and in the [public specification](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/6/a/3/0/7/37679-Intel_Cilk_plus_lang_spec_2.htm#array.ops)) so that no temporary is generated.

Not generating a temporary is consistent with C++'s philosophy of "abstraction with minimal penalty", and the fact that C/C++ do not generate temporaries for structure assignments.

See also slide 33 of my [ISC 2012 tutorial](http://parallelbook.com/article/isc-2012-tutorial-parallel-programming-cilk-plus).